# Can OS X be configured to avoid seeing a WiFi log in window when joining some networks?

Tags: macos, network, wifi, internet, login

In Mountain Lion (10.8), when you connect to a wireless network with a default login page - a special window pops up showing that page.  This pop-up is set to always in front, and also doesn't store any passwords / login information (unlike chrome, firefox, etc).  This is really annoying.

Is there anyway to make this popup window store passwords and login information or just disable that visual step altogether?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this thread](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3308224?start=0&tstart=0), you just need to rename the following file:

`/System/Library/CoreServices/Captive Network Assistant.app`

to something else and it will not show up anymore.

Comment: Yes, that does seem to work; and there don't seem to be any ways to adopt spellcheck...